# REDUX SLICES: Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux

i ran into a redux problem working on a project. I'm trying to set orderCancelling to true. But this error pops up when trying to run the dispatch.
I cant figure out the problem, does anyone have a clue to a solution?

Where i call dispatch:

```
export const cancelOrder = (exchange, order, account, dispatch) => {
  exchange.methods.cancelOrder(order).send({ from: account})
  .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
    //dispatch
    dispatch(exchangeSlice.actions.orderCancel())
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    window.alert('There was an Error')
  })

}
```

My slice

```
const exchange = createSlice({
  name: 'exchange',
  initialState: {
    contract: null,
    exchangeEtherBalance: 0,
    exchangeTokenBalances: 0,
    allOrders: [],
    cancelledOrders: [],
    filledOrders: [],
    openOrders: [],
    loaded: false,
    orderCancelling: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    set: (state, action) => action.payload,
    orderCancel: (state) => state.orderCancelling = true
  }
});
```

Comment: Does the following fix it: `orderCancel: (state) => { state.orderCancelling = true }`?

Comment: No, it throws the same error

Comment: You sure you really tried it? The change is that the orderCancel function is not returning anything now. Do you have a [minimal reproducible  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Comment: is this what you mean? 
`export const cancelOrder = (exchange, order, account, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(exchangeSlice.actions.orderCancel())
}`

Comment: No, change the reducer, not the action: `reducers: {
    set: (state, action) => action.payload,
    orderCancel: (state) => { state.orderCancelling = true; }
  }`

Comment: Yes, i did that but it is still throwing the same error

Comment: [Here is a sandbox with your reducer](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-httpsstackoverflowcomq652114091641941-1gcyp?file=/src/index.js:581-615) If I do the action from your question it will set the entire state to the value of `true` so the code in your question doesn't work at all. I don't get the error you are getting though so can you provide a reproducible example that gives you the error you describe?

Comment: I think I may found the root cause. "A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.contract`. Value: Contract"